# Get select box value onchange

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

The following script gives me the result of select box onchange. But along with value whole page again reloading. I have tried many things but of no use.

My code,

```
<script>
    $(function(){
      $("select[name='cname']").change(function () {
      var str = "";
      $("select[name='cname'] option:selected").each(function () {
            str += $(this).text() + " ";

          });

            jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:"",
            data:  $("form#a").serialize(),

            success: function(data){
                jQuery(".res").html(data);

                $('#test').html(data);


            }
            });  
            var str = $("form").serialize();
            $(".res").text(str);
    });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Can you make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)? Can't find a code that reloads the page.

Comment: Actually not reloading the page but the old displaying one more time.

Comment: refer [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7561569/jquery-ajax-passing-value-on-php-same-page]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a JSFiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/LU24D/1/ (smaller than yours) to show how the select change works.
Also, I decreased the amount of logic in your variable 'str'.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $("select[name='cname']").change(function (evt) {
 evt.preventDefault();
       var str = $("select[name='cname'] option:selected").text();
           alert(str);
     });
 });
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin. Its working in alert box, but can i access this value in a php varaiable

Comment: Sure, just append your ajax function to it again. You might want to put the attribute cache to false in your ajax call. See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Can you show it on fiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LU24D/2/ this should be it.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#nameFont').change(function() {


                    var nameFont=document.getElementById('nameFont').value;//alert(nameFont);

                    $('#nameFontDiv').html(changefontfamily);


         });
```