# JavaScript array to php script on the same php file

Tags: javascript, php

how can i pass an internal JavaScript array result to a internal PHP script in the same PHP file?

Comment: Ajax perhaps? Have you tried to Google this?

Comment: Or set the `stringified` values as value of hidden field and submit the form...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass JavaScript variables to PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917576/how-to-pass-javascript-variables-to-php)

Comment: Format the array as post data and load the page via ajax?

Comment: @Krii like so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7561569/jquery-ajax-passing-value-on-php-same-page

Comment: @Rayon Dabre : Thanks for the idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is executed before Javascript can be executed. PHP is server-side and Javascript client-side. (In normal case; disregarded node.js ...) You could use some GET or POST to reach what you want.