# post in ajax with php get me undefined index

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

i want to send/pass data from the client to server by (ajax to php) but when i try this code

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.ajax({  
    type: 'post',  
    url: 'loo.php', 
    data: { data: 'some data' },
    success: function(response,w) {
       console.log(w);
    }
});
    </script>
  <?php 
      echo $_POST['data'];
  ?>
```

in my browser i got `success` print out which mean that the javascript code is working fine i guess , by in php i got `Undefined index`
p.s my file name is `loo.php`  all the code is in the same file

edit: i have tried to separate my files like this:

> my loo.php file:

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'test.php',
    data: {data: 'some data'},
    success: function (response, w) {
        console.log(w);
    }
});
</script>
```

> my test.php file:

`<?php
echo $_POST['data'];
?>`

still got undefined index

p.s. i navigate Manual to test.php file after i run loo.php file

Comment: Your question is same like this. Please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7561569/jquery-ajax-passing-value-on-php-same-page).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Ajax passing value on php same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7561569/jquery-ajax-passing-value-on-php-same-page)

Comment: You should separate your code into 2 different files. Your `undefined index` is most likely happening on initial page load, when your POST data is not set

Comment: I have just edited the question. I think I figured out what is happening with you

Answer (score 1):

You get this error because when loading the page the POST request has not yet been sent. So show the submitted `data` only if it exists, otherwise, show the JavaScript code.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['data'])) {
    die($_POST['data']);
}
?>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'loo.php',
    data: {data: 'some data'},
    success: function (response, w) {
        console.log(w);
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: the data always doesn't exists that's my main problem.

Comment: @R3ter Where exactly do you check it? If you do it using `console.log(w)` — it’s wrong. You should use `console.log(response)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<?php 
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
    echo $data['data'];
?>
```

Comment: jQuery fixes the post for you so the `$_POST`-variable will be populated. No need to fetch anything from the input stream manually and decode it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Html file

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="data_value"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$( document ).ready(function() {

    $.ajax({  
        type: 'post',  
        url: 'loo.php', 
        data: { data: 'some data' },
        success: function(response,w) {

          $("#data_value").html(response);
        }
    });

});
```

PHP file (loo.php)

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change the handler this way:

```
    if(isset($_POST['data'])){
        function return_data() {
            die(json_encode($_POST['data'])));
        }
        return_data();
    }
```

Comment: Why would you 1. create a function for this? 2. json_encode the data when it's a string?

Comment: Your questions are fair. 1) For the above example, it is not necessary to create a separate function. But it may be worth doing this if you need to create ONE handler for ALL Ajax requests. 2) Not to do an extra check on the data type, in case we do not know the type of incoming data.

Comment: 1. Sure, but then you wouldn't create it inside an if-statement since it then would only exist if that specific if statement gets evaluated as true. Then you wouldn't be able to reuse the same function. 2. The problem with json encoding a string is that, although it's valid json, javascript won't be able to properly parse it. Javascript only accepts objects and arrays as json.

Answer (score 0):

Answer after you edit the question:

$_POST is the array sent by the HTTP Post request. so if the request to the page named test.php or whatever is not HTTP POST Request the $_POST array will be empty. but the $_GET array may have some data if you sent them.
and navigation to a page is a get request to that page unless you used a form with method="post".
so what you are doing with ajax call is correct. but navigating to test.php manually without a form with post method is not gonna fill the $_POST array.
because when you make the Ajax call, it is done, it just makes the post-call correctly and everything is ok but when you navigate to that page it is a get request and it won't fill the $_POST array.
to do so, you don't need ajax at all. you can have this form

```
<form method="POST" action="test.php">
    <input type="text" name="data" value="some data" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

so either you use ajax and handle whatever you want to handle in the ajax success method. or use form and send the request to the page and handle it there.

---

the answer to the question before the edit

**If they are in the same file it won't work** like that, because when the file loads the $_POST['data'] is not exists at all, and after you run the ajax call, it exists within that call, not in your browser window.

so you can check if $_POST['data'] exists so you are sending it from ajax call so you can return it and use it inside your ajax success function.

conclusion:

you cannot put them in the same file and expect ajax will load before the actual php.
**it will first load the whole file then it will run the ajax**.
**the undefined index is from the server** before you even see the HTML page.

A solution could be:

File with your html and ajax functions index.html

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.ajax({  
    type: 'post',  
    url: 'loo.php', 
    data: { data: 'some data' },
    success: function(response,w) {
       // use the response here
       console.log(w);
    }
});
</script>
```

and another with your logic loo.php

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/plain"); // if you want to return a plain text
// if you want to return json it could be header('Content-type: application/json');
echo isset($_POST['data'])? $_POST['data']: ''
?>
```